# Geom_points not being drawn on ggplot map

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, spatial, r-sf

I'm trying to overlay several points on a map I've created from a shapefile (downloaded at this [link](https://dataworks.siouxfalls.org/datasets/cityofsfgis::subdivisions/about)). I'm using the sf package to draw my maps and am able to get get the following map.

```
first.map<-ggplot()+ 
  geom_sf(data = shp)+
  ggtitle("First Map")
```

[image]
As you can see, this works fine, but when I try to overlay my points, I get the following results.

```
second.map<-ggplot()+ 
  geom_sf(data = shp)+
  geom_point(data=locations, aes(long,lat),inherit.aes = F)+
  ggtitle("Second Map")
```

[image]
I think this has something to do with how sf is interpreting the coordinates for my points, but I can't figure out how to get my point coordinates into what R wants me to. Below are the coordinates that I'm trying to overlay. I'm not super experienced with working with this type of data so any help would be appreciated.

```
locations<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                      long=c(96.73872,96.69264,96.69264,96.69250,96.68029),
                      lat=c(43.52769,43.53598,43.53598,43.54669,43.53585))
```

Comment: Look at `st_crs(shp)` and `st_coordinates(shp)`. Your CRS is based in US feet and seems to be on a very different scale from your locations data. I generally try to make all my spatial data into sf objects (or none of it) to avoid situations like this. Try making an sf out of the points and project to the same CRS as the districts

Comment: Amending my comment, your longitude components should be negative. That makes this borderline a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a strength of mine so was curious to play too.

I got it to work like this,

- converting the locations to an sf object
- transforming the shape to have the same crs
- editing the location longitude by adding `*-1` in the input data to swap from west to east

Keen to hear better practices from others but this should get you going.

```
shp <- st_read("Subdivisions/Subdivisions.shp")

locations<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
        long=c(96.73872,96.69264,96.69264,96.69250,96.68029)*-1,
        lat=c(43.52769,43.53598,43.53598,43.54669,43.53585))


locations_g <- st_as_sf(locations, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)
shp2 <- st_transform(shp, 4326)

ggplot()+ 
  geom_sf(data = shp2)+
  geom_sf(data=locations_g)+
  ggtitle("Second Map")
```